# Grouping a list

Tags: scala

I want to group elements of a list such as :

```
val lst = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

On transformation it should return a new list as:

```
val newlst = List(List(1),  List(1,2), List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3,4), Lis(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: Would be nice to see what you tried first, anyway: `(1 to lst.length).map(i => lst.take(i)).toList`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
lst.inits.toList.reverse.tail
```

Comment: Wow! Long live Scala collections!

Comment: This is more idiomatic than my answer :) I totally discovered something, thanks

Answer (score 3):

`(1 to lst.size map lst.take).toList` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not as pretty or short as others, but gotta have some tail recursion for the soul:

```
def createFromElements(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
  @tailrec
  def createFromElements(l: List[Int], p: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = 
  l match {
    case x :: xs => 
      createFromElements(xs, (p.headOption.getOrElse(List()) ++ List(x)) :: p)
    case Nil => p.reverse
  }

  createFromElements(list, Nil)
}
```

And now:

```
scala> createFromElements(List(1,2,3,4,5))
res10: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `foldLeft` seems to be more efficient, though ugly:

```
(lst.foldLeft((List[List[Int]](), List[Int]()))((x,y) => { 
   val z = x._2 :+ y; 
   (x._1 :+ z, z) 
}))._1
```